# Site Access control through a particular user field in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-permissions

I am trying to only grant user the access to the site if one of the user fields have a particular value.

If not, the site should show an access denied.

Is there an efficient way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

here is how you could do it

**OPTION1**

create a custom role let's say "limited access" with no permisions in website(edit/delete/view) except to create his account, this would be your default role for users

then create a custom role  let's say "premium access" with permision to view your content(or whatever)

In account settings add your custom field("access") with values you wish("limited", "premium").

```
/admin/config/people/accounts/fields
```

Add rulles module and create a custom rulle that on account creation/update if field_access == premium then update the role to "premium access".

After doing this you can manage the users from users roles

**OPTION2**

Again using rulles module you can check if your user has the value you need in his profile and redirect him to your page.

**OPTION3**

hook_init() and/or hook_boot() check if value in user account profile field and redirect him, something like that:

```
function hook_init(){
    global $user;
    $user_data=user_load($user->id);
    if($user_data->field_access['LANGUAGE_NONE'][0]['value']=='limited'){
        drupal_go_to('/content/limited');
    }
}
```